# Getting error while i create a prompt

Tags: sas, prompt

I need to create a prompt. Actually I created another two with no problem, but one of the variable is different while I was creating prompt. I needed to do macro with that as below:

```
         %macro param_list;
            %global
    list_selected
    ;
     %let i=1;
     %let p_lst_tmp = %scan(&VID,&i);
      %do %while(&p_lst_tmp ne);
    %let list_selected = &list_selected "%scan(&VID,&i)";
    %let i = %eval(&i+1);
    %let p_lst_tmp = %scan(&VID,&i);
       %end; 
        %put list_selected = &list_selected;
          %mend;
```

Then in the code I created

```
  PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE Student_Pre AS
  SELECT  t1.personid LABEL="PIDM" AS PIDM,
      t1.V_ID as VID,
          t1.FIRST_NAME
  FROM ENROLL.Student_Dim t1
 WHERE t1.v_id = &list_selected
  ORDER BY t1.personid;
   QUIT;
```

But this code gives an error, ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, !, !!, &, (, *, **, +, -, '.', /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, EQT, EXCEPT, GE, GET, GROUP, GT, GTT, HAVING, INTERSECT, LE, LET, 
              LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, OR, ORDER, OUTER, UNION, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

How should I change the code?

Comment: What is &VID?  Is that intended to be the contents of some variable, or is there a macro variable previous defined?  Ask what you're trying to do in more detail (what is VID, what does your prompt do, etc.), this is a pretty bad way to do whatever it is you're trying to do - a better way can be shown.

Comment: AT minimum, you need WHERE t1.v_id in (&list_selected), if it's actually a list (and may require additional work depending on what is in &VID).

Comment: VID is the prompt name. I need to create a parameter which is VID variable

Comment: My prompt is an easy prompt, user enters values, single value in single line.

Comment: What I did before is t1.v_id="&VID" without macro in the code. but with this variable doesn't work. So I need to create this macro. BUt still doesn't work. I hope it is clear

Comment: Is this an EG prompt?  What context is this in?  If you do `%put (&vid);` what results do you get from an example usage?

Comment: Yes, it is EG. I want to create parameters for this report. VID is a kind of ID, User wants to write the VID and see the report about that VID. Regular way which I do everytime doesn't work for this variable don't know why. And I searched and found this way. When I don't write  (WHERE t1.v_id = &list_selected) doesn't give any error but doesn't pick the VID variable.

Comment: That's creating a list, so if &vid can have multiple values, you have to use `in`.  If it's just one value, then you can probably do something like %sysfunc(compress(...)) to clean it up if the issue is unclean data.  Like I said, post your `%put (&vid);` .

Comment: Joe, can you explain what is %put (&vid) means. what should I do

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't understand what `%put` does, you're not really at a level that should be asking these questions.  Google some papers on SAS macro programming and learn it at least at a novice level.